# Not able to tick Checkboxes using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble checking checkboxes via JQuery - I have done this:

```
if(element[1]==3)
  alert('#'+element[0]+'_1');//shows #chk_1
  $('#'+element[0]+'_1').attr('checked', true);
  $('#'+element[0]+'_2').attr('checked', true);
  $('#'+element[0]+'_3').attr('checked', true);    
}
```

I know it gets to that point because I can see the alert window with the correct variable name. I have also included JQuery and my firebug isn't complaining about any errors, its just nothing is happening.

I have a few other functions which are active on a user click:

```
onclick="checker($(this).attr('id'));"
```

Which essentially checks if a user is allowed to tick the checkbox but this shouldn't get activated if I use the above method, correct? Plus I have done the automated ticks in such a way that those rules are preserved and the user is allowed to tick the checkboxes.

I am able to click the checkboxes and those rule checks are done correctly in the checker function.

HELP! I have no idea what's wrong to be frank.

I appreciate nay help.

### Update

With Pekka's advice I have found that no JQuery function seems to be working for example:

`$('#'+element[0]+'_1').hide();`

Did nothing. So it means the ID of the element has a problem? But the element does exist and its the correct name!

I have given the checkbox a value and tried this:

`alert($('#'+element[0]+'_1').val());`

I get "undefined" returned! Why?

### Update 2

Testing if it has been checked:

```
$('#'+element[0]+'_1').attr('checked', true);

if ($('#'+element[0]+'_1'+':checked').val() !== null) {
   alert('#'+element[0]+'_1');
}
```

This showed me the alert box. So it seems it is checked but I can not see it?

### Update - Solution

Don't be a noob like me and wrap JQuery code with: `$(document).ready(function() {`

I managed to waste everyones time having not done this, I think that bit of code is going to become standard for me from now on.

Thank you everyone for the continued help! :) I'll have to give to the person [lillq] that mentioned document load!

Comment: Can you try something simpler, like hide the element, to make sure you can address it at all using `$('#'+element[0]+'_1')`? I think this is an element access issue (e.g. a duplicate ID), the code to tick the box looks fine to me.

Comment: Good idea - I just did this `$('#'+element[0]+'_1').hide();` and this did not work either! I don't understand, the element does exist and its being referenced correctly! I have double checked.

Comment: I wonder what $('#'+element[0]+'_1').length is - is it actually finding something to check? Maybe try the same thing with document.getElementById and see if you get different results.

Comment: Can you post an on-line example? Can you search the HTML code for duplicate IDs?

Comment: Length returned 0 - what does that mean? @Pekka - I don't have duplicate ID's - I have searched the document (both the raw code and the served HTML). The name and ID is the same though, I don't think that makes a difference though.

Comment: jQuery returns arrays of matched elements - if the length is 0, it did not match any elements with your id.

Comment: Could this be a mix-up between prototype and JQuery? Do you happen to use prototype somewhere in the project? Because prototype's `$` needs the ID without hash `#`.

Comment: @Ray - are you sure about that? I can assure that element exists with that ID. Also have a look at my small test in my question (Update 2) - what do you think? @Pekka - I am not using prototype anywhere. Only JQuery.

Comment: @Abs - Your test for 'null' in update 2 should be a test for 'undefined'.

Comment: @Abs flawed logic in update 2, you are testing for values not equal `null`, but it could be that the operation fails and returns `false` (which is not === null).

Comment: I don't doubt that it exists - but for some reason jQuery isn't finding it. In your update 2 test, you are looking for anything that is not null. This will match 'undefined', which I would bet is what val() is actually returning.

Comment: Are your javascript files loaded in the proper order?

Comment: I assume your page has a `body` tag. What does the following alert return: `alert($('body').length)`

Comment: @Patrick - thanks for pointing that out - I have changed it to 'undefined' and I still see the alert box. Yes, my JS files are in the right order, I have checked this. Also firebug would of complained about missing variables/files so I am pretty sure.

Comment: I have updated my question again, just to show my full function which receives a string.

Comment: @Patrick - it returned 0 and then undefined! Before anyone asks I have a body tag!

Comment: Can you post an online example to look at?

Comment: But in update 1, you state that `alert($('#'+element[0]+'_1').val());` returns undefined. How then could the alert show up in your if statement that checks for **not undefined**?

Comment: If `body` is turning up a length of 0, then jQuery must not be loaded properly. Do you have any other jQuery code that works? Again, are your javascript files loaded in the proper order? (jQuery before yours.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a glitch somewhere, and not a JQuery bug. Maybe JQuery gets loaded twice?

Comment: @Patrick  - it returns 1 and my checkboxes now work. I needed to wrap my functions with `$(document).ready(function() {` - what a complete fail of a day. Epic Failure on my part.

Comment: Heh, don't worry too much - It happens to everyone, and just once. :)

Comment: This probably has happened to me several times before! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thought is:

If you have more than one `chk_1, chk_2, chk_3` ids in your html, the `$('#'+element[0]+'_2').attr('checked', true);` will only effect the first one in your document.

I ran the code you supplied as such:

html

```
...
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="el1" onclick="checker($(this).attr('id'));" />Text<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="el2" onclick="checker($(this).attr('id'));" />Text<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="el3" onclick="checker($(this).attr('id'));" />Text<br />
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    init();
</script>
```

javascript

```
function init () {
    $('#el1').attr('checked', true); 
    $('#el2').attr('checked', true); 
    $('#el3').attr('checked', true); 
}
function checker(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

The init function here checks all of the boxes after the document has loaded. Is there any other info that you could give us help out.

I like to reduce examples like this to the simplest code that fails.

Comment: OMFG thank you for mentioning document has loaded - I wrapped my JS functions with `$(document).ready(function() {` and everything works now! I can't believe this. What a waste of time, apologies everyone as well! I will edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `('#'+element[0]+'_1').click();`

Comment: What if it's checked already? Won't this uncheck it in that case?

Comment: You could use :not(:checked) to only select unchecked inputs

Answer (score 0):

Changing the checked state could perhaps trigger an onchange event, but certainly not a click event, so that is irrelevant.

You should not set the attribute to `true` but `"checked"`.

```
$('#'+element[0]+'_1').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

See this [FAQ entry](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_check.2Funcheck_an_input.3F).

Comment: I tried that already, but that doesn't work either! But I should be using that as best practice?

Comment: @Abs: According to the jQuery FAQ, yes you should. If it still doesn't work, verify that the element actually has that id (not just as name) and that you don't have duplicate id's.

Comment: **The FAQ is wrong.** `attr` sets (for the most part, except for a couple of workarounds) JavaScript properties and **not** HTML attributes. This is clear: if you set the `checked` HTML attribute that *does not affect* the checkedness of the checkbox, only the `defaultChecked`​ness to which that attribute maps. jQuery is setting the property, and thus the correct value to set it to is `true`. Though `'checked'`, like any other non-empty string value will still work because it is truthy.

Comment: I can confirm that I do not have duplicate elements, that a checkbox with that ID exists and is not duplicated.